# Command to change permissions only on files not directories

Tags: permissions, chmod, find, xargs

I have the following command

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

which would successfully change to 644 the permissions on all files in .,
provided that the filenames contained no embedded spaces.
However it doesn't work in general.

For example

```
touch "hullo world"
chmod 777 "hullo*"
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

returns

```
/bin/chmod: cannot access `./hello': No such file or directory
/bin/chmod: cannot access `world': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to modify the command so that it can deal with files with embedded spaces?

Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: The above example works perfectly fine for me. I think you're doing something wrong or your locale settings may be getting in the way

Comment: sidenote:  "./hello" and "hullo" are not the same ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without `xargs`

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

or with `xargs`

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} chmod 644 {}
```

---

*the used `xargs` switches*

- `-0` If there are blank spaces or characters (including newlines) many commands will not work. This option take cares of file names with blank space.
- `-I` Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input. Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.

Explanation taken from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/)

Comment: Thanks very much everybody.    As serg noticed something was indeed getting in the way, something incredibly stupid.    Once moved out of the way, all of the above suggestions work fine.